# how to just set one observer for a room query

Tags: android, observable, android-room, android-livedata

I'm using the room for storing some data in my local database which are fetched from the server-side.
these data will show in a recyclerView,
also there is a searchView that allows the user to search for some specific data.

now, I was wondering that is there any way I apply two of these features in one way?
I used this query to do that but it seems the observer won't trigger just for a change in the function's parameters:
[image]

in the other word, my question is:

Imagin I called this query like this:

```
database.searchFor(null,true).observe(this,observer{
....
})
```

how can I trigger the above observer after calling the query with another parameter like this:

```
database.searchFor("Alex",false)
```

should I change the structure and the way that I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using another LiveData and [Transformation's switchMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations#switchMap(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E,%20androidx.arch.core.util.Function%3CX,%20androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CY%3E%3E)).

Let's say you have ViewModel where you can declare 2 Livedata - first for parameters (`keyword` & `all`), and second - for db observing:

```
val params = MutableLiveData<Pair<String?, Boolean>>(Pair(null, true)) // <-- default parameters

val searchResults = Transformations.switchMap(params) 
    { 
       params -> database.searchFor(params.first, params.second) // <-- updates with parameters' changes
    }
```

In your Activity/Fragment you set parameters' values and observe results:

```
viewModel.searchResults.observe(this, Observer{
   ....
})

viewModel.params.value = Pair("Alex", false) // <-- to search results
```